# Informix iSQL date function help

Tags: function, date, informix, isql

I'm trying to extract just the year out of either of the built-in date functions of Informix
`TODAY` or `CURRENT`

Is there a way to do this without `SUBSTR()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: use the `YEAR` function:

```
SELECT YEAR(TODAY)
  FROM SysMaster::SysDual;
```

Similarly for MONTH, DAY, WEEKDAY (0..6).  You could use CURRENT instead of TODAY, but that generates a DATETIME value which is then converted to DATE and then analyzed.

Comment: you know... i was going to try that.. i swear